# Run a command on client machine without ActiveX using IE 11 Browser

Tags: javascript, html

Would like to run a command/script/exe/bat/shell on client machine using IE 11 Browser without ActiveXObject creation. Since ActiveX is disabled default

please help me to execute a command without ActiveX object creation.

Note: can't go for SSH using PHP

Comment: So you want to make a virus

Comment: Browsers dont have shell access to cliënt machines (for security reasons).

Answer (score 0):

There are only three ways I can think of to do this, none of which I think is likely to work for you:

1. ActiveX. You've said it's disabled and apparently you can't get it enabled, so that's probably not going to happen.
2. Write a .Net "no touch deployment" (NTD) application that does the work, roll out an Active Directory security policy allowing that application FullTrust to the target workstations, and have your web page in IE11 link to the application's .exe. Note that NTD is deprecated by Microsoft, but you can still build NTD apps with .Net 2.0. However, I suspect that if you can't get ActiveX enabled in your organization, you won't be able to get the necessary FullTrust permission pushed either.
3. Write a signed, unsandboxed Java applet, since I think IE11 still supports the obsolete Java plugin (Oracle no longer does, though). But I bet support for the Java plugin is also disabled by default, and of course you'd have to have the Java plugin installed on the target workstations, and writing a signed, unsandboxed Java applet is, again, markedly non-trivial.

I think if you have a legitimate reason for doing this, you're probably going to have to write a script or .exe and get users to download and execute it outside the browser. (It will, of course, be subject to their permissions.)

Comment: All the 3 possible ways can't be applicable/used for scenario/requirement. Could you please confirm me is there a possibility if i make my site allowed to known sites or something will it work with ActiveX ??

Comment: And I need to get the client username as well in the same way ? any possibility ?

Comment: @UndamatlaKailash: No, as far as I know there's no way to do this without security policy rollout, etc. (As for getting the user's username: That's trivial at the server end using Windows authentication server-side.)

Comment: Great to hear about the username. Do you have any sample stuff for this trivial at the server end?

Comment: @UndamatlaKailash: I suggest searching, using keywords related to the server-side technology you use.